# Can I a use a macro in a c struct declaration?

Tags: c, struct, macros

I have

```
struct foo {
    int var;
}
```

and a static declaration of foo

```
static const struct foo bar =  {
     .var = 8;
};
```

What I want to do is

```
#define sizeit(_struct) .var = sizeof(struct _struct)
```

so that I can do

```
static const struct foo bar = {
     sizeit(foo)
};
```

but I get a compiler error complaining that _struct doesn't exist.  I'm pretty sure it is because of the way the preprocessor handles macros.  Does anyone have a better suggestion?

I do not want to dynamically allocate the struct.

Comment: You should not use variables starting with underscore, they are reserved.

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c93b59bce5b07ee).

Comment: You have an extra semicolon on the line `.var = 8;` but otherwise the code compiles fine.

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: Macros are replaced before compilation. At compile time there should not exist any `_struct`. If the compiler complains that `_struct` does not exist maybe the macro definition is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> but I get a compiler error complaining that _struct doesn't exist

I have compiled your code. It compiles without any issue on my system. You shouldn't use the variable names starting with an underscore as they are reserved. It would be better if you could post the complete compiler's message.

```
struct foo {
    int var;
};

#define sizeit(x) .var = sizeof(struct x)


static const struct foo bar = {
     .var = 8
};

static const struct foo bar2 = {
     sizeit(foo)
};

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

To get `preprocessed` source code, we can use `gcc` with `-E` option. The preprocessed output is given below:

```
# 1 "stack_macro2.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "stack_macro2.c"
struct foo {
 int var;
};




static const struct foo bar = {
  .var = 8
};

static const struct foo bar2 = {
  .var = sizeof(struct foo)
};

int main()
{

return 0;
}
```

Comment: IIRC, names starting with a single underscore are reserved in global scope only, so I'm not sure it applied to macro parameters.